# swipe left/right event not working using jquerymobile for android

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

i am trying to use the swipe event to navigate between the pages, here is my code

```
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", page, function() { 
   $.mobile.changePage( "#"+next, { transition: "slide" },false ); 
}); // Navigate to next page when the "next" button is clicked 
$( ".control .next", page ).on( "click", function() { 
   $.mobile.changePage( "#"+next, { transition: "slide" },false ); 
});
```

But the swipe is not working properly on Android devices, any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think `swipeleft` is not an event with default jQuery. You will have to probably use some another library for that... hammarjs is popular one.

Comment: **jQuery.mobile.changePage** is **deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0** and **will be removed in 1.5.0**. Use the pagecontainer widget's change() method instead.

Comment: look at the demo in jquerymobile docs : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/swipe-page/

Comment: @QuickFix event the demo is working very poorly

Comment: actually I noticed that swipe behaviour depends a lot of the version of android.

Answer (score 1):

This would be to start the swipe
(

```
function( event ) {
  var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
      event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : event;
  return {
      time: ( new Date() ).getTime(),
      coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
      origin: $( event.target )
    };
}
```

)

And the when the swipe stops
(

```
function( event ) {
  var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
      event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : event;
  return {
      time: ( new Date() ).getTime(),
      coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
    };
}
```

)

This method receives the start and stop objects and handles the logic for and triggering for the swipe events.

(

```
function( start, stop ) {
  if ( stop.time - start.time < $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold &&
    Math.abs( start.coords[ 0 ] - stop.coords[ 0 ] ) > $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold &&
    Math.abs( start.coords[ 1 ] - stop.coords[ 1 ] ) < $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold ) {

    start.origin.trigger( "swipe" )
      .trigger( start.coords[0] > stop.coords[ 0 ] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight" );
  }
}
```

)

HTMl code 
(

```
<script>
$(function(){
  // Bind the swipeHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
  $( "div.box" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler );

  // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swipe' class to it
  function swipeHandler( event ){
    $( event.target ).addClass( "swipe" );
  }
});
</script>
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#"+next, { transition: "slide" },false ); 
//----------put changehash inside this--------------^^--^^^^
```

to this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#"+next, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
```